# Constructing $n$-Cube, $n$-Cell and $n$-Orthoplex Groups

Tags: group-theory, polyhedra

What are the properties of the rotating cube, tetra- and octahedron that give them the group structures they have, and can those properties be generalised to get at the group structure of their higher-dimensional analogues?  If so, is there a neat method that could be understood by an undergrad?

For background I'm preparing to start a course on groups next year, and this sort of thing is fascinating to me. Apologies if it's trivial!

Comment: What are the "rotating cube, tetra- and octahedron" as objects? Which is for instance the group structure on the "rotating cube"?

Comment: @dan_fulea The cube and octahedron both have (the achiral version of) [this group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry)

Comment: The question above was an other one, usually it is not a good framework for a question to mix and put in the same hat some geometric object and its group of symmetries. These are two different objects. The cube is realized in the euclidean (Hilbert space) $\Bbb R^3$, we have to fix some labels for its vertices, and the symmetry group is a group, a subgroup of all permutation of the vertices that preserve the metric structure. Under these circumstances, which is the question?

Comment: If I understand correctly I'm interested in the subgroups of all permutation of $n$, $2n$ and $2^n$ vertices that preserve the metric structure for a given $n$, i.e. those that correspond to rotations of regular $n$-polytopes

Comment: Then you might want to read about the Coxeter groups.